# How to get user input in python dictionary and print out?Btw i am newbie

Tags: python, dictionary

1.How to add user input to get the value of FEBRUARY after entering 'feb'
This is my codes:

```
  months_Conversion = {'feb': 'February', 'jan': 'January'}
  #input("Enter the words: ")
  print(months_Conversion.get("feb"))
```

2.output Works without user input

```
    months_Convert = {'feb': 'February', 'jan': 'January'}
    print(months_convert.get("feb")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a default value as an agrument in the get function to print out February even if the input is not a specified dictionary key:

```
 months_Conversion = {'feb': 'February', 'jan': 'January'}
 text = input("Enter the words: ")
 print(months_Conversion.get(text, "February"))  # "February" will be the response if the correct key is not paased
```